# How do I get the isalnum code to work for the specific problem?

Tags: python, typeerror

I've already applied the following code:

```
my1name = 'Alicia'
my2name = 'Shifflett'
yearP = '2019'
my1nameSpace = my1name + ''
print(my1name.isalnum())
print(my1name.isalnum())
print(yearP.isalnum())
```

The task wants me to apply isalnum() to the string my1name+my2name. I tried the following:

```
print(my1name+my2name.isalnum())
```

But I keep getting the error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bool") to str

How do I type this out correctly to get it to work?

Comment: The order of precedence matter. `(my1name+my2name).isalnum()` When you write `my1name+my2name.isalnum()`, what is happening is `my2name.isalnum()` gets evaluated first, which returns `True`, then `my1name + True` get evaluated, hence the error

Comment: To explain @hansolo's code, you're mistake was in first evaluating `my2name.isalnum()` (which is `True`) and then trying to add `my1name` to `True` which is what caused the error. The added parenthesis tell python to evaluate the string concatenation first, avoiding the type error.